# Remove from ObservableCollection items which name occurs on other list

Tags: c#, observablelist

I've got `ObservableCollection a` and `List b`

Now I want to remove from collection `a` elements that have their equivalent in list `b`.

My code at this moment:

```
public static void CrossRemove<TFirst, TSecond>(this ObservableCollection<TFirst> collection, IEnumerable<TSecond> secondCollection, Func<TFirst, TSecond, bool> predicate)
{
    collection.Where(first => secondCollection.Any(second => predicate(first, second)))
        .ToList().ForEach(item => collection.Remove(item));
}
```

usage:

```
ObservableCollection<string> first = new ObservableCollection<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "k" };

IEnumerable<int> second = new List<int> { 2, 3, 5 };

first.CrossRemove(second, (x, y) => x == y.ToString());
```

this code removes "2", "3" and "5" from collection leaving "1", "4", "6" and "k".

In my real code `a` and `b` contains elements that inherits from the same `interface` and I'm comparing property that is in that interface but I'm not able to take any adventage of it.

I can't make a new list because it's bound to wpf view and there will be visible glitches if I do that instead of removing items.

Is there any better / faster way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I can't think of a better way. You'd have to stick with this approach. May someone comes with better solution:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your second collection a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) for faster lookups. I also changed your [`ForEach` to a `foreach`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx). This is easier to demonstrate with properties, as in your original.

```
void Main()
{
    ObservableCollection<MyClass> first = new ObservableCollection<MyClass> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "k" };

    ISet<IMyInterface> second = new HashSet<IMyInterface>(new MyClass2[] { 2, 3, 5 }, new MyEqualityComparer());

    first.CrossRemove(second);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", first.Select(x => x.MyProperty)));
    // 1, 4, 6, k
}
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IMyInterface>
{
    public bool Equals(IMyInterface a, IMyInterface b)
    {
        return a.MyProperty == b.MyProperty;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(IMyInterface obj)
    {
        return obj.MyProperty.GetHashCode();
    }
}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void CrossRemove<TFirst, TSecond>(this ObservableCollection<TFirst> collection, ISet<TSecond> set) where TFirst : TSecond
    {
        foreach (var item in collection.Where(item => set.Contains(item)).ToList())
            collection.Remove(item);
    }
}
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator MyClass(string s)
    {
        return new MyClass { MyProperty = s };
    }
}
public class MyClass2 : IMyInterface
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator MyClass2(int i)
    {
        return new MyClass2 { MyProperty = i.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Even if the object don't share a common interface, you should be able to write an `IEqualityComparer<object>` that works with both correctly, e.g. if your lambda predicate would've been:

```
(TypeA a, TypeB b) => a.PropA == b.PropB
```

Then your class would be:

```
public class MyOtherEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    private object GetProperty(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is TypeA)
            return ((TypeA)obj).PropA;
        else if (obj is TypeB)
            return ((TypeB)obj).PropB;
        else
            throw new Exception();
    }
    public bool Equals(object a, object b)
    {
        return GetProperty(a).Equals(GetProperty(b));
    }
    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return GetProperty(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, I'll make good use of this :) Last thing: can you think of a better name than "CrossRemove" because it doesn't say much and english is not my native language ;)

Comment: There are several names you could use: `Difference`, `Complement`, or `Subtract` (from [the mathematical idea of a set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html)), or `RemoveAll` like `List<T>`'s method (except that takes a predicate, not a collection), or `RemoveWhere` like `HashSet<T>`'s method (which also takes a predicate). I think I'd go with `Subtract` or `RemoveAll`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest way to do this is with an equivalent of `List<T>`'s [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) function as it is more general. Instead of

```
first.CrossRemove(second, (x, y) => x == y.ToString());
```

I would write

```
first.RemoveAll(item1 => second.Any(item2 => item1 == item2.ToString()));
```

Unfortunately, `ObservableCollection<T>` does not have this method, so we need to write one:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void RemoveAll<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, Func<T, bool> pred)
    {
        var toBeRemoved = collection.Where(pred).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in toBeRemoved)
            collection.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The above extension method is very inefficient, others such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541789/337065) are algorithmically much faster. In this case though, I don't think that it's relevant as we're talking about an `ObservableCollection<T>` that is presumably bound to a view. Given this, we should only be doing a very small number of changes, otherwise the layout and re-rendering costs will be very high. If you are doing a large number of changes, then you should probably be replacing the collection with a new one so that the layout is only recalculated once.