# How to remove an item content from a list?

Tags: c#

I am using a stringsplitting mechanism for comma separated strings,and using a foreach loop for looping each item, So if I want to remove an item what can I do?

```
string lyrsct = drow1["lyricist"].ToString();
var delimiters = new[] {','}; 
var lyrsct1 = lyrsct.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var item in lyrsct1)
{
    if()
        {
         .........i need to remove from here.....
        }                 
}
```

I want to remove item inside the if loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# remove item from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018957/c-sharp-remove-item-from-list)

Comment: You can not remove from list **inside foreach loop**. instead use a for loop and handle index changes correctly. if you remove item from `lyrsct1` inside foreach loop you get InvalidOperationException : [Collection was modified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024179/c-sharp-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)

Comment: Which condition do you want? Any example input?

Comment: @X-TECH notice that `lyrsct1` and `lyrsct` is not a list. its an array

Comment: Provide input as you assigned to `lyrsct` and what is the expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you remove an item from a List<> whilst iterating through it in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541777/can-you-remove-an-item-from-a-list-whilst-iterating-through-it-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in lyrsct1)    
{    
      if (//item's condition)
      {
         lyrsct1.Remove(item );        
      }                   
}
```

Comment: first of all  `lyrsct1` is array.  second : if it was a list you would get InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution for removing items given that you have some condition on which to act.

I am removing '7' from lists.

```
    var condition = "7";
    string lists = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9";
    var delimiter = new[] {','};
    var splitlist = lists.Split(delimiter,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    var newList = new List<string>();

   foreach (var item in splitlist.Where(x => !x.Equals(condition)))
        {
            newList.Add(item);
        }
   OR

   var newList = splitlist.Where(x => !x.Equals(condition)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in lyrsct1.Where(x => !x.Contains("example text"))) // you can also compare values here instead of contains or !Contains (not contains)
{    
    result.Add(item);
}
```

OR

```
var lyrsct1 = lyrsct.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .Where(x => !x.Contains("example text")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify an array. you have to convert `lyrsct1` into list.

also you can not modify collection inside foreach loop when you are iterating over it. so use for loop instead

```
        string lyrsct = drow1["lyricist"].ToString();
        var delimiters = new[] { ',' };
        var lyrsct1 = lyrsct.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList(); // List is modifiable.
        for (int i = 0; i < lyrsct1.Length; i++)
        {
            var item = lyrsct1[i];
            if ()
            { 
                int indexToRemove = something; // index of item that should be removed
                lyrsct1.Remove(indexToRemove);
                if(indexToRemove <= i) i--; // correct the indexing
            }
        }
```

[from this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/759985/4767498)

> The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get
>   the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove
>   items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.
>   **If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a
>   for loop.**

Also take a look at :[Collection was modified. enumeration operation may not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024179/c-sharp-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to filter out some elements is to use .Where LINQ method. I assume that you you want to get an array of strings as a result:

```
string lyrsct = drow1["lyricist"].ToString();
var delimiters = new[] {','}; 
var lyrsct1 = lyrsct.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(item => !condition(item).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `List` containing only filtered elements:

```
string lyrsct = drow1["lyricist"].ToString();
var delimiters = new[] {','}; 
var lyrsct1 = lyrsct.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

List<string> newList = new List<string>(lyrcst1.Where(elem => !predicate(elem)));
```

Check the constructor taking `IEnumerable<T>`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx