# How can I do this special foreach iterator?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify or delete items from an enumerable collection while iterating through it in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308466/how-to-modify-or-delete-items-from-an-enumerable-collection-while-iterating-throu)

Listen, I do not want to know about the basic foreach. I am talking about that one which control this error:

```
"The enumerator is not valid because the collection changed."
```

Which occur when I do this:

```
foreach(Image image in images)
{
   if(...)
   {
       images.remove(image)
   }
}
```

I believe there is an special iterator which handle this well, as Java has.
So, how can I do this in C# please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Or just remove it without manually iterating at all:

```
images.RemoveAll(image=>...)
```

Works on `List<T>` but many other containers don't support it.

An O(n) solution working on `IList<T>`:

```
void RemoveWhere(this IList<T> list,Predicate<T> pred)
{
    int targetIndex=0;
    for(int srcIndex=0;srcIndex<list.Count;srcIndex++)
    {
      if(pred(list[srcIndex]))
      {
        list[targetIndex]=list[srcIndex];
        targetIndex++;
      }
      for(int i=list.Count-1;i>=targetIndex;i--)
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Can be sped up a bit by not assigning until you hit the first removed item.

Comment: in my case, I will only remove IF a condition is true.

Comment: The lamda is a condition. The name of the functions is misleading. I would have called it `RemoveWhere`

Comment: alas, RemoveAll is one of the LINQ extension methods, so naming it something else is pretty much not an option.  I agree, though, that this method, along with some others, were poorly named.

Comment: Doh! disregard my previous comment.  My brain must have been somewhere else; RemoveAll is not a LINQ method.  I should have realized, since the LINQ extension methods don't perform manipulations.  So anyway, I guess I'm just in agreement that the `RemoveAll` method is poorly named.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.Count; ++i)
{
    if (...)
    {
        images.RemoveAt(i);
        --i;
    }
}
```

Comment: but If I do this, I believe I will lose the next object, considering I am using Canvas. For example: Image that I removed the object of the index 2. So the object of index 2 will move to index 2 as a List. So when I try to get the next value which is index 3, the old object of index 3 will be at index 2. So I will lose him.

Comment: @Alan, that's the purpose of the line `--i;`.  This adjusts the index so that no items are missed.

Comment: that's what the `--i` corrects. The technique of decrementing when removing is interesting. I usually wrote my loop to go backwards and double-test sometimes.

Comment: This is O(n^2) for most containers. It's possible to write O(n) time and O(1) space solutions on `IList<T>`

Comment: It is also sometimes easier to loop backwards if you're removing items: for (int i = images.Count - 1; i <= 0; --i)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in C#.

What you can do is collect the objects you want to remove, then remove them:

```
Image[] imagesToRemove = images.Where(image => ...).ToArray();
foreach (Image image in imagesToRemove)
    images.remove(image);
```

Comment: And I think your code is typically O(n^2) since `Remove` on most collections is O(n). On `HashSet<T>` it would be fast, but HashSet already offers built in methods for this.

Answer (score 1):

Kent's answer will work given something that implements `IList<T>`.  For something that doesn't you will have to build up a list of the things you want to remove.  For example:

```
public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this ICollection<T> self, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var toRemove = self.Where(predicate).ToList();

    foreach (var i in toRemove)
        self.Remove(i);
}
```