# Remove selected item from ListView from ImageFileCollectionViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to remove the selected Item file from the list-view and also from the directory but I couldn't succeed. How can i remove this.?

```
string destination_dir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"./4x6";
    public ImggLList()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    ListViewImage.Items.Clear();
    DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;


    ImageFileCollectionViewModel ImagesViewModel = new ImageFileCollectionViewModel();
    ImageFileControler.CompleteViewList(ImagesViewModel, destination_dir);
    ListViewImage.DataContext = ImagesViewModel;
    }
```

OnDataContextChanged

```
private ImageFileCollectionViewModel _currentDataContext = null;
        private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_currentDataContext == DataContext) return;

            if (_currentDataContext != null)
                _currentDataContext.SelectedImageFileViewModels = null;

            _currentDataContext = DataContext as ImageFileCollectionViewModel;
            if (_currentDataContext != null)
                _currentDataContext.SelectedImageFileViewModels = ListViewImage.SelectedItems;

        }
```

Button Function:

```
 private List<ImageFileViewModel> copyOfSelection;

        private ImageFileCollectionViewModel imageFileCollection;
        private void Delte_Photo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            copyOfSelection = imageFileCollection.SelectedImageFileViewModels.Cast<ImageFileViewModel>().ToList();

            foreach (ImageFileViewModel ifvm in copyOfSelection)
            {
                copyOfSelection.Remove(ifvm);
                File.Delete(destination_dir);
            }

        }
```

NullExeception Error:
[image]

Comment: I don't believe you can modify a list in a foreach loop:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294983/modifying-list-inside-foreach-loop     and here     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308466/how-to-modify-or-delete-items-from-an-enumerable-collection-while-iterating-thro

Comment: @akousmata: How can i fix this? Please guide me.

Comment: Use a standard for loop as both of the links I provided suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < copyOfSelection.Count; i++)
{
    copyOfSelection.RemoveAt(i);
    File.Delete(destination_dir);        
}
```

Comment: I have initialized the ImageFileCollectionViewModel & ImageFileViewModel, i'm getting null error

Comment: In your `OnDataContextChanged` method you are setting the `SelectedImageFileViewModels` to null.  I'm not sure how your code works, but chances are that object is null when you are trying to reference it.  That has nothing to do with how to remove an item from a list in for loop though.

Comment: What is the best way to fix this problem? Thank you