# Unwrap hyphen separated numbers in a string into a range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with the beginnings of postal codes distinguished by regions in following form:

```
region A 385
region B 656 - 659
```

I need to unwrap the data with dash, so it will be:

```
region B 656, 657, 658, 659
```

My code

```
postcodes.iloc[:,1] = postcodes.iloc[:,1].apply(lambda x: x.split('—'))
def unwrap_codes(row):
row = row['Postcode begins with']
if len(row) > 1:
    for x, y in row:
        while x != y:
            row.append(x=+1)
postcodes['Unwraped'] = postcodes.apply(unwrap_codes, axis=1)
```

returns a ValueError: ('too many values to unpack (expected 2)'
Could you please help me to handle the error?

Comment: That indentation can't be correct .. and the error tells you that there are more than two elements in each entry in row.

Comment: Lists shouldn't be modified when you iterate through them. You should use another object like a stack. When you started to iterate the list maybe it had 2 elements but you are adding more elements as time goes by and that's the problem. Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294983/modifying-list-inside-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `str.split` followed by an `apply` seems to do it:

```
print(df)
     region   postcode
0  region A        385
1  region B  656 - 659

df['Unwrapped'] = df.postcode.str.split('\s*-\s*')\
             .apply(lambda x: range(int(x[0]), int(x[-1]) + 1))
print(df['Unwrapped'])
0                   (385)
1    (656, 657, 658, 659)
Name: Unwrapped, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer is great.  I was just bored and wanted to write something.

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, [0, 1]], names=[None, 'match'])
d = df.postcode.str.extractall('(\d+)').reindex(idx).ffill().astype(int)[0]

d.unstack().add([0, 1]).apply(lambda x: list(range(*x)), 1)

0                   [385]
1    [656, 657, 658, 659]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Excellence born from boredom!