# Safely remove list from list in loop

Tags: c#, list

I am iterating through all the list in mainlist and if a specific condition occur. I want to remove that specific list.

It is not working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mainList.Count; i++)
{
     if (mainList[i].Dead == true) //
     {
          mainList.removeAt(i);//what will be affect on mainList.Count;
     }
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify or delete items from an enumerable collection while iterating through it in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308466/how-to-modify-or-delete-items-from-an-enumerable-collection-while-iterating-throu)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
mainList.RemoveAll(x => x.Dead);
```

Comment: I'm starting to enjoy the taste of lamb

Answer (score 4):

The way you constructed your for loop, it will only work if `mainList.Count` stays constant, but you are removing elements during your loop.  Do you understand why that is a problem?  Whenever you remove an element you end up skipping the check of the element after it.

I think you could use `foreach` and `mainList.remove` but I'm not sure.  Another solution is to just make your loop count downwards:

```
for (int i = mainList.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (mainList[i].Dead == true)
    {
         mainList.removeAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: No you shouldn't use a foreach and remove, that will alter the list which you are iterating over which is a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do that since you are altering the length of the list when you are doing so. I would do it like this instead:

```
var newList = mainList.Where(y => !y.Dead).ToList();
```

Comment: this doesn't remove the elements, though, it would require a further step to remove all the items in newList from mainList...

Comment: no, it doesn't remove the item it creates a new list. The accepted solution does the samething behind the scene but with a delayed execution.

Comment: well, it looks like the accepted solution is iterating backward through the list, and using RemoveAt(i) to remove the items, so I'm not sure I understand what you mean. (unless you mean the other proposed possible solution which was incomplete and commented on as a bad idea.) regardless, no offense was intended, I was just pointing out that your response does not answer the question, figuring you had forgotten to include the final step.

Answer (score 0):

[How to modify or delete items from an enumerable collection while iterating through it in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308466/how-to-modify-or-delete-items-from-an-enumerable-collection-while-iterating-throu)

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/238241-how-do-you-modify-array-while-iterating-through