# Getting InvalidOperationException when modifying the collection while loopng through it

Tags: c#, exception

I have a collection lets say list of integers and looping through it using foreach, but if I have to insert data into the list during the loop, how do I do that ? I'm getting

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was
>   modified enumeration operation may not execute.

This is the sample code below. I thought AsReadonly() would return a collection that was prior to modified state. That is not the case here.

```
ints = new List<int>(30);
ints.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
int y = 11;

foreach(int x in ints.AsReadOnly())
{
    ints.Add(y++);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity? what does the snipped above do? I am asking because it is not even possible to suggest you an alternative approach without understanding what is your real use case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify or delete items from an enumerable collection while iterating through it in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308466/how-to-modify-or-delete-items-from-an-enumerable-collection-while-iterating-throu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned `AsReadonly()` only produces a wrapper around the original list.

Something like this would work. But I am not sure what you are trying to do so it might not be helpful.

```
var ints = new List<int>();
ints.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
int y = 11;

var moreInts = new List<int>();

foreach(int x in ints.AsReadOnly())
{
    moreInts.Add(y++);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

ints.AddRange(moreInts);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a copy of the list that can't be modified.  This works:

```
foreach(int x in ints.ToArray())
{
    ints.Add(y++);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

The copy is unpleasant of course.  In this particular case, since you are only adding elements, you can avoid the copy by using a for() loop:

```
int count = ints.Count;
for (int ix = 0; ix < count; ++ix) {
    ints.Add(y++);
    Console.WriteLine(ints[ix]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) states `AsReadonly()` is only a *wrapper* on the original collection so you are still operating on the same collection - the same rules apply.

> A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper
>   that prevents modifying the collection; therefore, **if changes are made
>   to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those
>   changes.**

Comment: It's not a decorator - more likely a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Comment: @Jonathan: yes, you are right - decorator doesn't apply since the interface is actually different (since it can't allow modification)

Answer (score 0):

You cant modify a collection while inside `foreach` loop. Try to use `for`-loop instead.

Comment: You can't modify the collection you are iterating on. But you can modify another collection, which makes the `ToArray()` approach Hans mentioned in a comment possible.

Answer (score 0):

The AsReadOnlyMethod() returns a wrapper list that prohibits modification, it is still the same list.