# Disposing of nested collection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, filehandle

I have a set of objects, each of which has a collection of objects in it (those are obvious from the code below).  I want to create a 'dispose' method that goes through, getting rid of all the attachments and then the sections, so I can delete the related files.  The objects are used in various spots so the 'using' method isn't appropriate as far as I can see.  The below fails (understandably) because the collection has been modified.

```
// Find files and get names.
foreach (DocumentSection s in this.sections)
{
    foreach (EmailAttachment a in s.SectionAttachments)
    {
        // Get file location, then clear attachment to release file handle.
        filesToDelete.Add(a.TempAttachmentFileLoc);
        s.SectionAttachments.Remove(a);
        a = null;
    }
    this.sections.Remove(s);
    s = null;
}
```

The reason I'm doing all this is because I want to delete the temp file after use (TempAttachmentFileLoc) but it's in use and can't presently be deleted.

Comment: you don't ask a question..... you've waffled about something, and how you want to solve it. :)

Comment: Iterate backwards + remove last? Or use a Clear method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308466/how-to-modify-or-delete-items-from-an-enumerable-collection-while-iterating-thro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not clear the list after you've enumerated it?

```
// Find files and get names.
foreach (DocumentSection s in this.sections)
{
    foreach (EmailAttachment a in s.SectionAttachments)
    {
        // Get file location, then clear attachment to release file handle.
        filesToDelete.Add(a.TempAttachmentFileLoc);
        //s.SectionAttachments.Remove(a);  // removed this!
        //a = null;
    }
    s.SessionAttachments.Clear();  // Added this
    //this.sections.Remove(s);  // Removed this
    //s = null;
}
this.sections.Clear();  // Added this
```

That should do what you're attempting.

Comment: Come to think of it, since you're going to clear the entire `sections` collection. there's no need for the `s.SessionAttachments.Clear()`. Assuming the collection and the document aren't referenced anywhere else, they will be cleaned up on the next garbage collection after the call to `this.sections.Clear()`.

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I've done this and still have weird file handle issues.  Appreciate your effort though, I'm sure this does the disposing without issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the items from the list to `Dispose` them.  Just iterate over your list, and dispose each one in turn.  If you want to empty the collection, do it after the loop is complete.