# Selected Items in listview count = 0 even if items are selected from checkbox

Tags: c#, listview

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int i=listView1.SelectedItems.Count;
            int j = listView1.SelectedIndices.Count;
            for (int k = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; k++)
            {
                listView1.Items[k].Remove();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I am selecting values from listview why is it returning count = 0 ?

Comment: wich part is returning 0 more exactly?

Comment: int i=listView1.SelectedItems.Count;
            int j = listView1.SelectedIndices.Count;

these both parts returning 0..no item is selected..it is saying...help.

Answer (score 0):

The property `SelectedItems` returns the items that are selected, i.e. marked by clicking on the text (usually with a blue highlight).

To get the items whose checkboxes are checked, use the `CheckedItems` property.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the collection that you use in for statement. Take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308466/how-to-modify-or-delete-items-from-an-enumerable-collection-while-iterating-thro) for removing item from collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust  your `DataBind` of ListView in : ! IsPostBack  section

You persist your datas with ViewState

```
If(! IsPostBack)
{
  //You don't pass by this section when you post => you don'y erase your selected values 

  //Bind your ListView
}
```

Your datas are erased because when you post by clicking, you re-build your ListView et so erase selected values

Answer (score 0):

You can use listview's property `CheckedItems` to check for all items that were checked.